# get value variable outside fb.api with callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I know the problem with ajax and return variables, I was reading in stackoverflow about this, I know that I have to use a callback function, but in my case didn't work, of course something I'm making wrong

My code is this:

```
var id_user=get_id_user_login();//undefined??????????

function get_id_user_login(){
    FB.api(                                                
         '/me',                     
          {fields:'id'},
          function(response){//callback       
                 console.log(response.id);//OK
                 return response.id;
           }
     );             
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can´t just return the value because it´s asynchronous. Try this:

```
function customFunction(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

function get_id_user_login(){
    FB.api(                                                
         '/me',                     
          {fields:'id'},
          function(response){   
                 customFunction(response.id);
           }
     );             
};

get_id_user_login();
```

Comment: yes really I tried this, thanks a lot. I wrote this because I was thinking that this is very "spaghetti" no?, if I write some functions like this... but ok, look that is the only way.....

Comment: well, this is the best solution. but it of course depends on your whole project, of course it will look a bit different in a bigger one. don´t forget to accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: this is ok if you can rely on the ID being passed back in the response. If you work with a response with no ids like /{pageId}/ratings then how do you cross-reference it?

Answer (score -1):

Perfect, this is the example that work fine:

```
function mostrarInvitaciones(){
FB.login(function(response)
{   
    var object = { method: 'apprequests', 
          message: 'Message Txt',
          filters: ['app_non_users'],
          max_recipients: '1',
          redirect_uri: 'here the url app'
    };
    // Function callback for get the values, because the Fb.api is async.
    function callback(response){
            function obtenerDatosLoginUsuario(id, name) {
                //console.log('Id Usuario desde custom: '+id);
                //console.log('Nombre usuario desde custom: '+name);
                document.getElementById('miid').innerHTML = id;
                document.getElementById('minombre').innerHTML = name;
            }
            function obtenerDatosAmigo(id, name) {
                //console.log('Id Amigo desde custom: '+id);
                //console.log('Nombre Amigo desde custom: '+name);
                document.getElementById('idamigo').innerHTML = id;
                document.getElementById('nombreamigo').innerHTML = name;
            }
            // Datos del Login Usuario
            function datosLoginUsuario(){
                FB.api('/me',{fields: 'name'}, function(response)
                {
                    //console.log(response.name);
                    //console.log(response);
                    obtenerDatosLoginUsuario(response.id,response.name);
                });
            }
            // Datos del amigo seleccionado
            function datosAmigoInvitado(){
                FB.api('/'+ response.to, function(response)
                {
                    //console.log(response.id);
                    //console.log(response.name);
                    obtenerDatosAmigo(response.id,response.name);
                });
            }
            // Call the function
            datosLoginUsuario();
            datosAmigoInvitado();

    };      
    // Facebook UI
    FB.ui(object, callback)

})
```

}